# scala - matching by datatype string and get its frequency

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the below datatype details from a hive table schema and need to get its frequency

```
val a = List("decimal(10,2)","string","string","decimal(6,0)",
              "timestamp","decimal(8)", "timestamp" )

val freq = a.map{
  x => x match {
    case  x.contains("decimal") => "decimal" // getting error here
    case "string" => "string"
    case "timestamp" => "date"
  }
}.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)

println(freq)
```

I get error saying, cannot resolve symbol.. what is wrong with the code?.

I need the output as

```
Map(date -> 2, decimal -> 3, string -> 2)
```

If there are better ways to get the above output, that is also welcome

Comment: Should not it be `case x if x.contains("decimal") =>` ? Also, you do not need the `x => x match` part, just pass the cases to map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also `fold` over the `List`.

```
val freq = a.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)){
  case (m,s) if s.startsWith("decimal") => m + ("decimal" -> (m("decimal")+1))
  case (m,"timestamp") => m + ("date" -> (m("date")+1))
  case (m,str)         => m + (str    -> (m(str)+1))
}
```

Comment: great answer using foldLeft.. it works.. I'm learning something new.. thank you very much

Comment: just realized that startsWith() is more accurate than contains().. thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You can use a guard in the first pattern match to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
val freq = a.map{
  x => x match {
    case  x if  x.contains("decimal") => "decimal" // getting error here
    case "string" => "string"
    case "timestamp" => "date"
  }
}.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```